# bubble size distribution in bubble column using image processing technique

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a video from which I have extracted several frames. I need to analyse them to get the total number and the sizes of the bubbles. The program I have so far can identify a single bubble in the image but has trouble to determine multiple bubbles.

code:

```
clc;
clear all;
close all;
% ----------------- Select the image -------------------------------
% Double click the image fle to be selected
[FileName,PathName] = uigetfile('*.png','Select the image');
file = fullfile(PathName,FileName);

img=imread(file); % Reads the image
rgb = imcrop(img);
figure,imshow(rgb)
d = imdistline;   %to find the appropriate radius range

delete(d);
gray_image = rgb2gray(rgb);
figure, imshow(gray_image);
impixelinfo
[centers, radii] = imfindcircles(rgb,[3 10],'ObjectPolarity','dark')
hold on
[centers, radii] = imfindcircles(rgb,[3 10],'ObjectPolarity','dark', ...
    'Sensitivity',0.96)
hold off
figure, imshow(rgb);

h = viscircles(centers,radii);
[centers, radii] = imfindcircles(rgb,[3 10],'ObjectPolarity','dark', ...
    'Sensitivity',0.96);

length(centers)
delete(h);  % Delete previously drawn circles
h = viscircles(centers,radii);
%second method(2 stage )
[centers, radii] = imfindcircles(rgb,[3 10], 'ObjectPolarity','dark', ...
          'Sensitivity',0.96,'Method','twostage');

delete(h);

h = viscircles(centers,radii);
```

[The Frame Given As Input To Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYe7g.png)
[Output i am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KL8On.png)

I need help to get the correct number of bubbles in the image.
since in output screenshot there is some cluster where algo fails to get the correct number of bubbles.